# Importing Grafana dashboard - label_values doesn't work with InfluxDb

Tags: prometheus, grafana, influxdb, resilience4j

I found nice Grafana dashboard for Resilience4j metrics: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/grafana-1

The problem is that I am using InfluxDb data source but the dashboard was created for Prometheus.

I am getting errrors after import:

```
Templating [application]
Error updating options: InfluxDB Error: error parsing query: found label_values, expected SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL at line 1, char 1
```

I was looking for solution but I am new both to Grafana and InfluxDb and I am lost. Could you direct me somehow how can I adapt the dashboard so that it works with InfluxDb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InfluxDB and Prometheus use different query languages and concepts. So there is no simply way how can you "translate" PromQL (Prometheus query language) to InfluxQL (InfluxDB query language). You will have to learn both and you will need to rewrites all those queries manually, so they will be matching your InfuxDB data model.